# How to make parent component listen for both child component changes?

Tags: angular, angular7

I have a structure like this:

```
<parent-component>
   <child-component [input]="name"> </child-component>
   <child-component [input]="name> </child-component>
</parent-component>
```

To listen to the child component I'm using `@ViewChild`. The problem is that it only listens for the first child.

I made a stackblitz to reproduce the situation:

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ld7mpv)

There you can see that only the first "newName" is displayed to the console and not both of them. Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To listen for both, you can use two ViewChilds. Assign References to them in the .html file and specify which listener listens on which.

In your `app.component.html` it should be something like:

And then you can set up the listeners in your `app.component.ts` like so:

```
  @ViewChild('viewChild1') myFormValues;
  @ViewChild('viewChild2') anotherFormValues;
  informationInParentChild1;
  informationInParentChild2;

   constructor(private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.informationInParentChild1 = this.myFormValues.myForm;
    this.informationInParentChild2 = this.anotherFormValues.myForm;
    this.cdRef.detectChanges();
  }

  submitForm() {
    console.log(this.informationInParentChild1.value);
    console.log(this.informationInParentChild2.value);
  }
```

I modified your stackblitz example, its working [there](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8yymap).

Regards.

Comment: That's excatly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `@ViewChild` you can use `@ViewChildren` so you will get both the component data 
here i attach the log of the `myFormValues` 
[here is the `@ViewChildren` doc link](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren) 
[image: here you can see the console log of the object]

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment yet, but agree with Will Taylor. Please have a look [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aocmcv) for a two-way binding example with your example. There is no need for a dependency to ChildComponent.

Answer (score 0):

Really, for the situation show in your StackBlitz you should just emit an event in the child component, using an [@Output](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event) and then handle that event in the parent component.

Using this method creates looser coupling between your components than ViewChild/ViewChildren, as the latter introduces the need for the parent to know more about the implementation of the child.

If you have a situation that requires the parent component to call a method on the child component, then using `@ViewChildren` is the correct solution, as outlined by Yash Rami's answer.

Comment: Do you have any example with an @Output when a submit button is in the parent?